# Is it necessary to set "CarouselView_Experimental", "SwipeView_Experimental", "IndicatorView_Experimental" with XF version 4.6 pre?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

My app is currently setting:

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "CarouselView_Experimental", "SwipeView_Experimental", "IndicatorView_Experimental" });

Can someone tell me if it's still needed to set these with Version 4.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the official release notes for 4.6, the following are in preview and can only be accessed using feature flags :

- Shell_UWP_Experimental
- IndicatorView_Experimental
- SwipeView_Experimental
- AppTheme_Experimental
- CarouselView_Experimental
- MediaElement_Experimental
- StateTriggers_Experimental
- Markup_Experimental
- Expander_Experimental

So, yes you need to still keep that code there if you are using those 3 features in Xamarin Forms.

Link for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.6/4.6.0-pre4